# como recargar un grafico que presenta datos mediante stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen dia,

tengo un procedimiento almacenado para cargarle a un grafico los productos que mas se seleccionan para ventas. cree un metodo en c# para llamarlo:

```
private void Graficoproductospreferidos()
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("ProductosPreferidos", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Producto.Add(dr.GetString(0));
            CantidadSalidas.Add(dr.GetInt32(1));
        }
        chartproductospreferidos.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(Producto, CantidadSalidas);
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();

    }
```

el problema esta en cuando realizo una venta, si llamo al metodo nueva vez me carga el metodo sobre el anterior es decir me duplica los datos. como hago para que no los duplice sino que solo actualize?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la declaración de `Producto` y `CantidadSalidas`? ¿dónde los creas o inicializas?

Comment: Creo que tu solución es simple, en el mismo método deberías limpiar las variables `Producto` y `CantidadSalidas`, junto con refrescar la información del gráfico `chartproductospreferidos`. Debes limpiar estas variables según al tipo de datos que correspondan.